# Useffect is called repeatedly after passing dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, use-effect

Here after I was navigating on `ListPage.js` from `EditPage.js` file (i.e after clicking on submit button) my `ListPage.js` is not refreshing, and if I try to pass 'value' (i.e use to render my warehouse array list) as variable inside useEffect() in ListPage.js it calls api again and again. here I am using react-redux to fetch api

**ListPage.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { showDATA, regFilterCard, spaceFilterCard } from '../../../redux/dispatchAction';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Modal,
  Alert,
  Pressable,
} from 'react-native';
import WareCard from '../../components/WareCard/WareCard';
import styles from './styles';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

function ListPage(props) {
  const {navigation, value, detail} = props;

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.showDATA();
  }, [value]);

  function spaceFilter(){
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
    props.spaceFilterCard()
  }

  function registerFilter(){
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
    props.regFilterCard()
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Warehouses</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}>
          <MaterialIcon name="filter-alt" style={styles.filter}></MaterialIcon>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Modal
        animationType="fade"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}>
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => spaceFilter()}>
              <Text style={styles.modalText}>Space available</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => registerFilter()}>
              <Text style={styles.modalText}>Registered</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollPage}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {value && value !== undefined && value.length > 0 ?
        value.map((data, index) => {
          return (
            <WareCard
              city={data.city}
              cluster={data.cluster}
              name={data.name}
              id={data?.id}
              space_available={data.space_available}
              type={data.type}
              is_live={data.is_live}
              navigation={navigation}
              is_registered={data.is_registered}
              code={data.code}
              key={index}
            />
          );
        })
        :
        null
      }
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    value: state.warehouses,
  }
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  showDATA,
  spaceFilterCard,
  regFilterCard,
})(ListPage);
```

**EditPage.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import {showCardDetail, editCardDetail} from '../../../redux/dispatchAction';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {
    widthPercentageToDP as wp,
    heightPercentageToDP as hp,
  } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import axios from 'axios';

function EditPage(props) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [lopen, setLopen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
  const [lvalue, setLvalue] = useState(false);
  const [reg, setReg] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [city, setCity] = useState();
  const [space, setSpace] = useState();
  const [live, setLive] = useState();
  const [cluster, setCluster] = useState();
  const [editId, setEditID] = useState();
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'},
    {label: 'No', value: 'No'},
  ]);
  const [litems, setLitems] = useState([
    {label: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'},
    {label: 'No', value: 'No'},
  ]);

  const {navigation, route, detail} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    props.showCardDetail(route?.params?.id)
    setEditID(route?.params?.id)
    setName(detail?.name);
    setCity(detail?.city);
    setCluster(detail?.cluster);
    setSpace(detail?.space_available);
    if(detail?.is_registered){
      setReg("Yes");
    }else{
      setReg("No")
    }
    if(detail?.is_live){
      setLive("Yes");
    }else{
      setLive("No")
    }
  },[])

  function onSubmit(){
    setValue(!value)
    const profile = {
      name,
      city,
      cluster,
      space_available:space,
      is_registered:reg == 'Yes' ? true : false,
      is_live: live == 'Yes' ? true : false
    }
    props.editCardDetail(editId, profile);
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.page}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}>
        <MaterialIcon style={styles.clear} name="clear"></MaterialIcon>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.code}>{detail && detail !== undefined ? detail?.code : ''}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Name:</Text>
        <TextInput
          underlineColorAndroid="black"
          style={styles.textinput}
          onChangeText={(e) => {
            setName(e)
          }}
          value={name && name !== undefined ? name : ''}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>City:</Text>
        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="black" onChangeText={(e) => setCity(e)} value={city && city !== undefined ? city : ''} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Cluster:</Text>
        <TextInput underlineColorAndroid="black" onChangeText={(e) => setCluster(e)} value={cluster && cluster !== undefined ? cluster : ''} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Space Available:</Text>
        <TextInput keyboardType='numeric' underlineColorAndroid="black" value={space && space !== undefined ? space.toString() : ''} onChangeText={(e) => setSpace(e)} maxLength={10} />
      </View>
      <View style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Registered:</Text>
        <DropDownPicker
        containerStyle={{
            width:wp('30%'),
        }}
        style={styles.drop}
          open={open}
          value={reg && reg !== undefined ? reg : ''}
          items={items}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setReg}
          setItems={setItems}
          onChangeValue={val => {
            console.log(val, 'val');
            setReg(val)
          }}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>Live:</Text>
        <DropDownPicker
        containerStyle={{
            width:wp('30%'),
        }}
        style={styles.drop}
          open={lopen}
          value={live && live !== undefined ? live : ''}
          items={litems}
          setOpen={setLopen}
          setValue={setLive}
          setItems={setLitems}
          onChangeValue={val => {
            console.log(val, 'val');
            setLive(val)
          }}
        />
      </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submit} onPress={() => {
        onSubmit()
        navigation.navigate('List')
      }}>
          <Text style={styles.submitText}>SUBMIT</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    detail: state.cardReducer,
    editDetail: state.editReducer
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  showCardDetail, editCardDetail
})(EditPage);
```

**dispatchaction.js**

```
import data from '../data.json';
import axios from 'axios';

export const showDATA = () => async dispatch => {
  await axios.get("https://datadb122.herokuapp.com/warehouses/")
  .then(result => {
    console.log('data', result.data);
    dispatch({type: 'SHOW_DATA', payload: result.data})
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e, 'e'))
  
};

export const showCardDetail = id => async dispatch => {
  await axios.get(`https://datadb122.herokuapp.com/warehouses/${id}`)
  .then(result => dispatch({type: 'SHOW_CARD', payload: result.data}))
  .catch(e => e,'e')
};


export const editCardDetail = (idd, profile) => async dispatch => {
  console.log('idddddddddddddd ', idd, profile);
  await axios.patch(`https://datadb122.herokuapp.com/warehouses/${idd && idd !== undefined ? idd : ''}`, profile)
  .then(result => {
    console.log('edit profile ', profile);
    console.log('edit result ', result.data);
    dispatch({type: 'EDIT_CARD', payload: result.data})
  })
  .catch(e => e,'e')
};

export const spaceFilterCard = () => async dispatch => {
  await axios.get(`https://datadb122.herokuapp.com/warehouses/`)
  .then(result =>  {
    let arr = []
    result.data.map((d, i) => {
      if (d.is_live){
        arr.push(d);
      }
    })
    dispatch({type: 'SPACE_FILTER', payload: arr})
  })
  .catch(e => e,'e')
};

export const regFilterCard = () => async dispatch => {
  await axios.get(`https://datadb122.herokuapp.com/warehouses/`)
  .then(result =>  {
    let arr = []
    result.data.map((d, i) => {
      if (d.is_registered){
        arr.push(d);
      }
    })
    console.log('arrrrrrrrrrr', arr);
    dispatch({type: 'REG_FILTER', payload: arr})
  })
  .catch(e => e,'e')
};
```

**store.js*

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {warehouses} from './reducer';
// import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import {cardReducer} from './showCard';
import { editReducer } from './EditCard';


const middleware = [thunk];

const allReducers = combineReducers({
  warehouses,
  cardReducer,
  editReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(allReducers, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ListPage from './src/screens/ListPage/ListPage';
import DetailPage from './src/screens/DetailPage/DetailPage';
import EditPage from './src/screens/EditPage/EditPage';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './redux/store';


function App() {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <>
      {/* <ListPage /> */}
      <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="List" component={ListPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={DetailPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Edit" component={EditPage} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you might want to show your reducer logic. It's considered good practice to just declare values in your dependencies that you will be using in scope of an useEffect callback. `value` there don't seem to be used at all. I'm going to assume `value` is being updated at every call of `props.showDATA()` which will induce an infinite loop you have described since every render `value` is of a different object reference since Arrays are just objects. `[ ] !== [ ]`.

Comment: yes it is going in infinite loop, so how can i prevent that or how i should update my ListPage.js ?

Answer (score 0):

> Value will be changed multiple times. so, prop. show data called multiple times. You can remove the value in the array.
> Try this step or pass the id (When will you need to call the props. show data method.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        props.showDATA();
      }, []);
```

Comment: I tried this but after to navigation to ListPage.js it does not shows any value, as you can see I am fetching this by redux so it is taking little bit of time.